# Purifycss not deleting unused css class

Tags: html, css, node.js, purifycss

I have this code trying to delete the class 
`hello3`:

```
var purify = require('purify-css');
    var content = '<div class="hello"></div><div class="hello2"></div>';
    var css = '.hello { color: green; } .hello3 { display: block; }';

    var options = {
      output: 'purified.css',

      // Will minify CSS code in addition to purify.
      minify: true,

      // Logs out removed selectors.
      rejected: true
    };

    purify(content, css, options);
```

The output in purified.css is the same as the variable css:

```
.hello { color: green; } .hello3 { display: block; }
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Purify CSS looks to compare classes used in your html and php and other template files; I can only imagine you are using those classes somewhere so Purify is not removing them. Docs here: https://github.com/purifycss/purifycss

Comment: That's my full code, I even replicated the same as the docs and still not working.

Comment: It's difficult to tell because I can't see your templates code. Do you have a url? I am guessing you are using those classes in your templates and so the remove step is not running for those classes.

Comment: I am using content and css directly. I think I have found a bug, if I change `hello2` for `aaaa` then it works properly.

Comment: Well, if I only change `hello2` it won't work, but if i change `.hello3` for `.h` then it will delete `.h`. I guess it is not reading the number at the end of the class.

Comment: Yes I should have thought of that first, numbers aren't acceptable classes, or at least ones Purify.css is programmed to recognise. :)

Comment: I meant, something like ".example3" If you have in the html file `<div class="example"></div>`, then in the css `,example3{color:red}`, then it will assume that example3 is the same than example. I could check the code in Github and I found the error, I just fixed it but I am having some problems with the encode of part of the regx, no to much experience with javascript.

Comment: try a test with example-three instead. I reckon Purify css won't allow or detect classes with numerals in them.

Comment: I am building my own tool with python, using beautifulsoup and cssutils.

Answer (score 1):

I ran a test and confirmed that purify-css doesn't like class names that contain numbers.

My command... `purifycss css/main.css page1.html --out css/purified.css --info --rejected` took my main.css file and incompletely purified it into:

```
.page1-h1 {
  color: red;
}
.page2-h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

This included an unused class (.page2-h1). But when I renamed my class names so that there were no number characters in it and then ran the same command again got the main.css that I expected which contained only:

```
.pageone-hone {
  color: red;
}
```

This seems to be a [known problem](https://github.com/purifycss/purifycss/issues/147) too.